# Android NullPointerException on RoomDatabase object after application close

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, singleton, android-room

When i am trying to access RoomDatabase object inside my RepositoryProvider singleton class I get NullPointerException after closing my app. Do you know what is cause of this strange behaviour? AppDatabase is initalized in SplashActivity.
So far i've tried to replace my "synchronized singleton" with "enum singleton" and also add static prefix to database object but nothing seems work.

```
public class RepositoryProvider {
    private static RepositoryProvider INSTANCE;
    private TrainingSummaryRepository trainingSummaryRepository;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private BluetoothDeviceRepository bluetoothDeviceRepository;
    private TrainingActivityRepository trainingActivityRepository;
    private AppDatabase appDatabase;
    private ExternalStorageDatabase externalStorageDatabase;
    private TrainingRepository trainingRepository;
    private FriendRepository friendRepository;

    public static RepositoryProvider getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (RepositoryProvider.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = new RepositoryProvider();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void initDatabase(Context context) {
        appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "nutpro-db")
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                .build();
        userRepository = new UserRepository(appDatabase);
    }

    public void initExternalStorageDatabase(Context context, String appFileSystemName) {
        externalStorageDatabase = new ExternalStorageDatabase(context, appFileSystemName);
    }


    public TrainingRepository getTrainingRepository() {
        if (trainingRepository == null) {
            trainingRepository = new TrainingRepository();
        }
        return trainingRepository;
    }

    public FriendRepository getFriendRepository() {
        if (friendRepository == null) {
            friendRepository = new FriendRepository(appDatabase.friendDao(), getUserRepositoryInstance());
        }
        return friendRepository;
    }

    public ExternalStorageDatabase getExternalStorageDatabase() {
        return externalStorageDatabase;
    }

    public TrainingSummaryRepository getTrainingSummaryRepositoryInstance() {
        if (trainingSummaryRepository == null) {
            trainingSummaryRepository = new TrainingSummaryRepository(appDatabase);
        }
        return trainingSummaryRepository;
    }

    public UserRepository getUserRepositoryInstance() {
        return userRepository;
    }

    public BluetoothDeviceRepository getBluetoothDeviceRepositoryInstance() {
        if (bluetoothDeviceRepository == null) {
            bluetoothDeviceRepository = new BluetoothDeviceRepository(appDatabase);
        }
        return bluetoothDeviceRepository;
    }

    public TrainingActivityRepository getTrainingActivityRepository() {
        if (trainingActivityRepository == null) {
            trainingActivityRepository = new TrainingActivityRepository(appDatabase);
        }
        return trainingActivityRepository;
    }

    public void clear() {
        if (appDatabase != null) {
            appDatabase.clearAllTables();
        }
    }
}
```